# How to use a single <p:messages> for a specific form without duplicating p:growl

Tags: validation, jsf-2, primefaces, message

I'm using PrimeFaces 5.0 and have a problem with the basic validation messages.
I've many `<p:inputText>` fields that are all required, how can I link a single `<p:messages>` to all fields?

If I use the `for` attribute I can link it just to a single text field.
If I don't use the `for` attribute the `<p:messages>` tag catches also messages that are not for him (it duplicates the messages sent to the `<p:growl>` tag for example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just tell the `<p:messages>` to not redisplay (duplicate, as you say) the already displayed messages. Provided that the `<p:growl>` in question is being placed in the view *before* the `<p:messages>`, then it's a matter of setting its `redisplay` attribute to `false`.

```
<p:growl ... />
...
<p:messages ... redisplay="false" />
```